# Stellar data for data mining

Tags: star, data-analysis

Where could I find detailed data from stars? Like spectrum, x ray and so on ?

Because I would like to do some data analysis on it.

Comment: What have you already tried?  I don't really understand "I want to do data analysis". Data analysis is not an end in itself.

Comment: Far too vague to be a useful question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sloan Digital Sky Survey website has a good page with lots of links on it to retrieve spectra in different ways, you can access it [here](https://www.sdss3.org/dr9/spectro/). The most useful of these is probably [this one](http://dr9.sdss3.org/). This is just one of many places you can search but its a good starting point if your just curious about analysing spectra and not too picky about the source.